# How to debug into unmanaged code with VS code when debugging C#

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, unmanaged

I'm using VS code on ubuntu. My program is a C# program which calls some interfaces from a native C++ .so  with a C# binding layer. I can use dotnet core to debug C# part. And use GDB to debug native part seperately. But is there a way to debug into unmanaged code directly when launching from C# code? I know VS pro edition can support it. But anyone know how to do it with VS code on ubuntu?